# Form based Authentication using C# failing for the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, form-authentication

I am trying to implement form authentication in asp.net for one of my applications under default website in IIS to prevent anonymous users from accessing the website and I am facing some issues when I try to do this

I have the below settings done in web.config file for this application to implement form-auth. I have included the machine key tag, authentication tag for form-based auth and authorization tag to deny anonymous user

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="cookiename" cookieless="UseCookies" path="/" protection="None" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

In the IIS UI,

- .NET Authorization rules have Anonymous Users with Deny Rule and All Users (of Inherited type) with Allow rule
- Also, under Authentication UI, I have Anonymous Authentication disabled and From based Authentication enabled (Do we need to disable the Anonymous authentication here?)

When user logs into our portal, a cookie gets assigned to this user so that IIS can keep track of user's identity and gets navigated to the application (Aspx page) for which I am trying to implement form authentication. I am using webclient to post some request to perform some validation before navigating to this application and I am using CookieAwareWebClient to handle the cookies.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
  public CookieAwareWebClient()
  {
     CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  }
  public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
  {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
    request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
    return request;
   }
 }
```

Using the CookieAwareWebClient, I am trying to post the request. Here, authenticationCookie is the cookie which gets created right after user login and I am setting this value to myCookie object so that IIS can keep track of user's identity

```
using (CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
{         
  Cookie myCookie = new Cookie();
  myCookie.Name = authenticationCookie.Name; 
  myCookie.Value = authenticationCookie.Value;
  myCookie.Domain = URL.Host;
  client.CookieContainer.Add(myCookie);                    
  client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

  byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", reqparm);
}
```

When I try to post the request to the URL, the identity of the user is lost somewhere even though the web client has cookie container which holds the cookie value, and I am getting 401 error

```
 Remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorized
```

Because of this, IIS thinks the user as anonymous and hence not able to load the application. Is this the right way to handle form-auth to prevent anonymous users from accessing website and where am I going wrong? I am using IIS 8.5 version

Comment: Why are you testing with `CookieAwareWebClient` rather than with an actual web browser?

Comment: I am using webclient to post some request for the new application and I need to make sure I find a way to retrieve the authentication cookie from the request after logging in and pass it along WebClient, so that the application can think the request is coming from authenticated user and not anonymous user. I thought CookieAwareWebClient can do the job.

Comment: Put `CookieAwareWebClient` to one side. Does forms authentication, within a web browser, work? Are you able to login and use the app (in Google Chrome)?

Comment: I am able to login to the application using google chrome, but the application is not loading as IIS thinks the user as anonymous since I implemented Form authentication. I am not able to maintain the identity of the user when the control gets redirected to this application.

Comment: I think you will need this command FormsAuthetication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username)